# Cannot compile under optimisation using VS due to an issue with memcpy; treated as an intrinsic function

Tags: c++, c, optimization, visual-studio-2013

I am using visual studio at the moment to do something that is quite simple:

```
memcpy(real, real_, n, sizeof(float));
```

where read and real_ are pointers of type float*; pointing to the start of two blocks of allocated memory of size = n*sizeof(float). I have no problem compiling this without optimisation but once I compile under /O2. The compiler throws the following error:

```
Error   32  error C2167: 'memcpy' : too many actual parameters for intrinsic function
```

I cannot understand this as I have disabled intrinsic functions and the "CFLAGs" in the build command line does not include /Oi

I am assuming therefore that O2 does this as default. Therefore, I used the pragama compiler directive to locally switch of both optimisation and/or intrinsics with no effect.

At this point I am completely baffled. What's more I have never had any problem with this. I am currently working with VS 2013. MSDN is of little or no use in this matter.

EDIT:

Do'h - thanks The Dark. I was sending down four rather than three arguments - see memcpy(3). However, this was compiling (without even a warning) and working fine when compiled under no optimisation.

Comment: Nothing to do with intrinsic - `memcpy` takes 3 parameters, not 4. You probably want to do * instead of , between the last two parameters.

Comment: Excellent. How on Earth was it compiling without a warning (and working) with very large arrays.

Comment: A missing `#include <string.h>`?

Comment: @cdcdcd It would be a good idea to investigate your compiler settings, so that it detects argument mismatches.  In C++ and in C99 this should happen by default;  but may not be possible in MSVC's C mode

Comment: M.M. Thanks - you're right that the extra argument will just be ignored under some conditions. But even with this these is a problem here, even if everything compiled ok, copying n bytes rather than n*4 bytes should've resulted in different results. These are .c files so therefore function overloading is not a solution either. I am very perplexed but I will do as you suggested.

Answer (score 1):

There are indeed too many arguments in your code fragment. Rewrite it as:

```
memcpy(real, real_, n * sizeof(float));
```

And make sure you include `<string.h>`

The real question is:

- Why does the offending code compile without `/O2` at all?

Do you have warnings enabled? Do you get any?

Comment: Thanks chqrlie - this is bizarre. Including string.h doesn't change anything. The only thing I can think of is that n, by some fluke is larger than I think it is. I can't debug the code right now but will do when I get a chance.